# Filter through CSV files based on name and updateselectizeInput on R shiny

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I am new to RShiny (and R in general) and cannot quite figure out how to do the following thing. I have a list of 50 CSV files ending in either P2.csv,P3.csv or P5.csv. I would like to make an app that would allow the user to select a specific price (P2,P3,P5) and then present them with the list of csv files with that ending pattern out of which the user could then select maximum 3 that would need to be loaded into memory.

I have found separately how to list all the files with the specific ending and I figured that I would need to use updateSelectizeInput so that each time the user selects a price (e.g. P2) he gets presented with all the csv files appleP2.csv, orangeP2.csv etc for example, but cannot think of a way to make this work.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

```
library(shiny)

#listing the csv files ending with a same pattern 
same_price_P2<-list.files(pattern="P2.csv")
same_price_P3<-list.files(pattern="P3.csv")
same_price_P5<-list.files(pattern="P5.csv")

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Price of fruit"),
  
  #user can select the price of the fruit
  selectInput("Price", "Price", choices = c("5 euros"="P5", "2 euros"="P2", "3 euros"="P3"), selected="P2", multiple=FALSE)),
  
  #user must be presented only with the CSV files associated to the selected price and can select maximum of 3 
  #files to be read 
  selectizeInput("Fruit", "Fruit", choices = "", selected = NULL, multiple=TRUE, options=list(maxItems=3)),
  

  
  tableOutput("dataset")
)


shinyServer(function(session, input, output){
  
  
  #Populate this by filtering through and showing the csv files based on whether they end in P2.csv, P5.csv, P3.csv
  #the selected files by the user should then be read
  observeEvent(
    input$Price,
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "Fruit", "Fruit", 
                      choices = ................[..........==input$Price]))
  
 
  output$dataset <- renderTable({
    data
  })
  
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already found the main steps.

The last steps are:

1. Insert all possible csv names (regardless of the ending) in the `choice` argumente of the `selectizeInput` function. (We need this vector for the second step too, therefore it is specified outside of the `selectizeInput` function. -> `all_price`)
2. Filter the `choices` by the `input$Price` variable inside the `updateSelectizeInput`.
3. Load tables into memory.

The code below will help you with the first to steps. Because that seems to be the issue you are currently working on.

```
library(shiny)

#listing the csv files ending with a same pattern 
same_price_P2 <- c("appleP2.csv",  "bananaP2.csv", "cranberryP2.csv", "dateP2.csv")
same_price_P3 <- c("appleP3.csv",  "bananaP3.csv", "cranberryP3.csv", "dateP3.csv")
same_price_P5 <- c("appleP5.csv",  "bananaP5.csv", "cranberryP5.csv", "dateP5.csv")
all_price <- c(same_price_P2, same_price_P3, same_price_P5)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Price of fruit"),
  
  #user can select the price of the fruit
  selectInput("Price",
              "Price",
              choices = c("5 euros" = "P5", 
                          "2 euros" = "P2",
                          "3 euros" = "P3"),
              selected = "P2",
              multiple = FALSE),
  
  #user must be presented only with the CSV files associated to the selected price and can select maximum of 3 
  #files to be read 
  selectizeInput("Fruit",
                 "Fruit", 
                 choices = all_price, 
                 selected = NULL, 
                 multiple =  TRUE,
                 options = list(maxItems = 3)),
  
  
  textOutput("dataset")
)


server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  
  #Populate this by filtering through and showing the csv files based on whether they end in P2.csv, P5.csv, P3.csv
  #the selected files by the user should then be read
  observe({
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 
                         "Fruit", 
                         "Fruit", 
                         choices = grep(paste0(input$Price,
                                               ".csv$"),
                                        all_price,
                                        value = T))
    })
  
  
  output$dataset <- renderText({
    input$Fruit
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That's great, thank you very much, it works!     Do you have any tips for the loading of the selected files from the user? I have found it's possible to do it by letting the user select files from fileInput, but not sure how it'd work here